# CNN Back-propagation on a 3d image

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, backpropagation

So, I am trying to write my own code for CNN using CIFAR-10 dataset. I have completed the feed forward algorithm and started with the back-propagation. I had no problem back propagating through the fully connected layer as well as going through unpooling. I am now stuck at back propagating through a convolution layer. My image input size is (32, 32, 3) rgb input.
This is my network so far.

Conv Layer + Relu -> Maxpool -> Conv Layer + Relu -> Maxpool -> Dense + Relu -> Dense + Softmax

While propagating forward, I took a (3, 3, 3) kernel and convolved with the image. I used 12 such filters, which gave me (32, 32, 12) tensor as an output. Maxpool made the dimensions (16, 16, 12) which was again convolved with (3, 3, 12) for 8 different filters to get (16, 16, 8).

While back propagating, I have reached this part. I have a (16, 16, 8) tensor, using which i have to update a filter matrix of (3, 3, 12) for 8 different filters. Also I have to propagate my error to calculate change in the input of the previous layer which is of the dimension (16, 16, 12).

I understood how this works with 1 channel image, but I'm confused when three channels are concerned.
I also know that back-propagating through a convolution layer is also a convolution, but I'm stuck here. How is it done. Please help.

Comment: This post explains really well how to back-propagate in CNN. https://towardsdatascience.com/gentle-dive-into-math-behind-convolutional-neural-networks-79a07dd44cf9

Comment: Thanks!! That helped